# Bootstrap form not in the center of the div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstraap form where two field I have added the class `.d-inline-block` so that it comes next to each other and I have another field where I have not added the class so that It comes below of the two field.

I want this to be in the center of the div which I am not able to do it. Only the first two fields are coming to center but not the last div.

Can someone point out the mistake?

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.d-inline-block {
  
  width: 40%;
}

.message {
  width: 80%;
}

.formClass {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="formClass ">
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Name </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group message">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97avbgsq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap 4, you can use the helper classes `.d-flex .flex-wrap .justify-content-center` on the parent.

```css
.d-inline-block {
  width: 40%;
}

.message {
  width: 80%;
}

.formClass {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="formClass d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Name </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group message">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But if you want to use your original code, to horizontally center a block element with a `width`, use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` or `margin: auto` for short if that works for you. You can also do that using the `.mx-auto` bootstrap helper class.

```css
.d-inline-block {
  width: 40%;
}

.message {
  width: 80%;
}

.formClass {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="formClass ">
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Name </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group message mx-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: As you have said `to horizontally center a block element with a width, use margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` I have used it but why do you need an extra `margin-auto` for the message input element?

Comment: @this.Believer you have to assign the width and margin to the same element. You had width 80% on `.message` and margin auto on `.formClass`

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the third DIV and give that `display: inline-block;`:

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.d-inline-block {
  
  width: 40%;
}

.message {
  width: 80%;
}

.formClass {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
}
.x {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form class="formClass ">
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Name </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group message x">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
    <div class="form-control-placeholder"> Phone </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tyuxpzk9/1/

Comment: Bootstrap 4 has utility display classes like `.d-inline-block` which do the same as `.x` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

While you're free to create your own custom CSS classes to control form field sizes and position, I would like to suggest using the built in grid system column classes to control the size and position of the input fields.

[**Bootstrap 4 Grid System**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 offset-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
      <label class="d-block text-center" for="nameInput">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
      <label class="d-block text-center" for="phoneInput">Phone</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput">
      <label class="d-block text-center" for="phoneInput">Phone</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>
```